# How subclass a WinApi Edit control using a delphi VCL component?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm trying to [subclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#subclassing_window) an [WinApi edit control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and override the paint method . so far i'm using the [SetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and  the **GWL_WNDPROC** flag to override the original window procedure, then I receive the WM_PAINT message and use my own Paint logic, this is working good, but  I'm wondering if it's possible create a *shadow* TEdit component and pass the original handle of the Winapi EDIT control  to the Delphi TEdit component and in  that way i can use the shadow TEdit to get and set the properties of the EDIT control. Is that possible?

**Update**

Following the Remy suggestion about using the `WindowHandle` property I ended with this code, but is not working (setting the color of the edit control has not effect).

```
type
   TWinControlCracker= class(TWinControl);

Var
 ShadowEdit : TEdit;
 newWndProc : Pointer;
 EditHandle : NativeInt;
begin
 EditHandle:=$00320530;//this is the handle to the EDIT control
 ShadowEdit:=TEdit.Create(nil);
 TWinControlCracker(ShadowEdit).WindowHandle:=EditHandle;
 newWndProc := MakeObjectInstance(ShadowEdit.WindowProc);
 SetWindowLong(EditHandle, GWL_WNDPROC, NativeInt(newWndProc));
 ShadowEdit.Color:=clLime;
 ShadowEdit.Refresh;
end;
```

Comment: What's a shadow component? Is that a Delphi concept?

Comment: by "shadow" i mean create a "fake" TEdit VCL control.

Comment: Alright. Well in that case I'm not aware of any functionality in WinAPI that allows any such thing short of editing the resource file of the executable (if one exists).

Comment: Using a "shadow" `TEdit` to set the `Color` of an Edit `HWND` will not work because it requires cooperation from the Edit control's parent window. When an Edit control needs to be painted, it sends a `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` message to its parent window to get an `HBRUSH` handle that is used during the painting. Your `TEdit` shadow will never receive that message unless you subclass the parent window and forward the appropriate messages manually. For native VCL windows, the VCL handles all of that redirecting for you so a `TEdit` (or any `TControl` descendant in general) can process its own messages.

Comment: [GWL_WNDPROC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#gwl_wndproc) doesn't work across processes.

Comment: @TOndrej, The window which have the EDIT control is created by a dll loaded by my application.

Comment: @Salvador I was assuming something like that, since you said it was working. In that case, the phrase "external application" you used in the title was misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TWinControl` (which `TEdit` derives from) has a public `WindowHandle` property that you can assign a non-VCL `HWND` to.  Just be sure to set the property back to 0 before you destroy the `TEdit` or do anything that might cause it to call its `RecreateWnd()` method internally, otherwise the WinAPI control will get destroyed.  And don't use anything that requires the `TEdit.Parent` property to be meaningful.

Comment: How can we even be sure what he means when he says "An external application".

Comment: I try using your suggestion, but is not working can you show me a basic code sample or review my updated question?

Comment: What you are attempting to do with the `Color` property will not work.  See my other comment to your edited question.  Any functionality that involves the parent window receiving messages will not work unless you subclass the Edit control's parent window as well.